# Dapper insert: flatten class for insert

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper

I have a class with an embedded subclass such as this

```
    public class Parent
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get;set;}
        public ValidFor ValidFor { get; set; }
    }

    public class ValidFor 
    {
        public DateTime? StartDateTime { get;set;}
        public DateTime? EndDateTime { get; set; }
    }
```

But upon Insert with Dapper I want to flatten out the ValidFor so that I just insert into a single "Parent" table.  My insert code and SQL is below

```
  public async Task<Category> Create(Category entity)
  {            
      string sql = "Insert into Parent (Id, Name, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) values (@Id, @Name, @StartDateTime, @EndDateTime)";

      using (var connection = GetConnection)
      {
          await connection.ExecuteAsync(sql, entity);
          return entity;
      }
   }
```

But I am getting the error

> "StartDateTime" does not exist

I understand why, but how can I Map my Object to my table?  The examples I can find online about Multi-Mapping all focus on multiple tables.

I could of course create a different class which is flat and matches my table structure and then Map between them (using Mapster/Automapper etc.), but as I have 10s of classes with this issue then that is not really practical.

Comment: And how are you making your parameters? Show the actual code that runs the insert

Comment: @CaiusJard  Added insert code.

Comment: Why are you not using inheritance here? I mean, `Parent` could just derive from `ValidFor`. That seems more logical from an entity point of view. Else you will have constant mapping from one type to the other, making things inefficient (in my experience).

Comment: @JHBonarius I hid some complexity, so my Parent is already inheriting from another class, (which actually inherits from another!), So I can't also inherit from ValidFor.

Comment: That sounds like a major architectural issue! If the entities in the DB don't represent the actual domain models, then something has gone seriously wrong. I mean, you will now need to write something like "projection classes" to be able to store and load the base entities. That's not good...

Answer (score 1):

I think something is seriously wrong with your architecture, but anyhow:

The simplest fix is just do specify the parameters manually in an anonymous object.

```cs
public async Task<Category> Create(Category entity)
{            
    string sql = "Insert into Parent (Id, Name, StartDateTime, EndDateTime) values (@Id, @Name, @StartDateTime, @EndDateTime)";

    using (var connection = GetConnection)
    {
        await connection.ExecuteAsync(sql, new
        {
            entity.Id,
            entity.Name,
            entity.ValidFor.StartDateTime,
            entity.ValidFor.EndDateTime,
        });
        return entity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note it seems a bit weird to me that you are returning the input argument from the method...

Comment: I appreciate the help, but while that might work my classes are actually much more complex and manually mapping all the properties from all the classes would be too much effort, and is effectively just creating a different Class (albeit via an anonymous object) and mapping which I stated I was trying to avoid.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith you are underlining my point. There is no simple fix for this. This really is a fundamental architecture design issue in your system. You really want you models to be equal to the database entities.